# Unresolved problem from comments based on another user's question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was intrigued by a question asked by another user, and although I didn't provide an answer, I engaged in externded chat with a user who did. He gave me lots of great advice, and gave me a lot of his time. The last comment ended in him pointing me in the right direction. I don't feel I can ask any more of him, since he has already helped me in understanding the problem so much already. Is it acceptable to pose a question based on my partital understanding of the problem, referencing his ideas and requesting clarification?

To clarify, a link to the question (and the numerous comments!) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341929/sum-numbers-game).

The comment I require clarification (and possibly extended explanation of) is:

> that limit is the ratio of the coefficients of the eigenvector corresponding to the larger eigenvalue (which you can take at any $n≥216$ because it doesn't change beyond $216$). So compute ($a_{216},b_{216}$) for both strategies, decompose that with respect to the eigensystem of the recurrence matrix, and form the ratio of the coefficients corresponding to the larger eigenvalue.

I was not unfortunately able to achieve this.

Comment: If your question meets the guidelines for a quality post on MSE, then I don't see why not. Your hesitance is a lack of understanding?

Comment: @DonkeyKong My hesitance is twofold: 1) That I would be asking someone else (potentially) to clarify his comments. 2) That I would be asking a question based on a question that has already been officially answered.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Since I have a lack of understanding in the area, I may be taking his comments out of context, which I know can be potentially contentious.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think context might help, if the comments haven't been deleted? So long as you're not asking what a list of things some user told you mean, how they relate to one another, etc. (_extremely broad and multi-faceted_) and instead have some sort of particular problem you are focusing on,  I would err on the side of saying your question would probably be alright. But I'm rather new here, might want to wait for a more experienced user.

Comment: @DonkeyKong should I post the link to the question here to clarify?

Comment: I don't think it could hurt.

Comment: @DonkeyKong ok, added to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

more noticeable this way. I asked joriki to email me, which he has done. If you do the same, I can forward each to the other and then you can directly email each other after that.

You can find my email address by looking at [my profile here in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy?tab=profile) or by using my last name at http://www.ams.org/cml/

I don't know what time zone you are in. If you leave me a comment here I can also put my address for you in a return comment (if you are unable to find it through the CML or profile, that has happened sometimes). I just don't want that visible here for 24 hours straight.

Comment: that really is very kind - of both you and joriki :) Will email you shortly.